# How to determine a percentage gain or loss for a series of people in a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've posted a few questions about a system I'm trying to write, and feel bad for asking so many questions. However, I'm still quite new (or revisiting from years ago) to the finer elements of SQL Server, so please forgive and help me!

I have imported data from a JSON into a table, which has a whole host of different information contained within it, one of which being a person's weight recorded over time. I have the following code to produce this:

```
SELECT ServiceUserID, PersonID, ServiceUser, DateDone, [Weight]
FROM
(    SELECT ServiceUserID, PersonID, ServiceUser, DateDone, LEFT(SUBSTRING(cn.Fragment, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', cn.Fragment), 8000),
           PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(cn.Fragment, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', cn.Fragment), 8000) + 'X') -1) AS [Weight], ra.ScoreMeaning
FROM [JSONCareNotes-HOME] cn 

LEFT OUTER JOIN [JSONRAs-HOME] ra ON ra.PersonID = cn.ServiceUserID

WHERE cn.SliderData LIKE '%weigh%'
and cn.Fragment NOT LIKE '%weighed%'
) AS SubQueryAlias

WHERE NOT ([Weight] IS NULL OR [Weight] = ' ')
ORDER BY ServiceUser, DateDone DESC
```

What I get from this is (a sample):

```
7e54d569-0ad2-43a9-aada-5f37480fdfd4    NULL    Resident 1      2019-11-16  83.1
19e0d4b1-8fe4-4480-b99b-5d067123121e    NULL    Resident 2      2019-11-16  63.8
ba2a406f-2e28-4186-a5a0-95d93bb20ca9    NULL    Resident 3      2019-11-10  54
ecfa663b-3dd2-4aef-b25c-e43dd6b82ebb    NULL    Resident 4      2019-11-16  81.5
8a5880af-1d7f-4b96-ae28-4de4fb1a4685    NULL    Resident 5      2019-11-28  60.9
8a5880af-1d7f-4b96-ae28-4de4fb1a4685    NULL    Resident 5      2019-11-21  61
8a5880af-1d7f-4b96-ae28-4de4fb1a4685    NULL    Resident 5      2019-11-01  62.05
91495cd7-054d-47d5-9be0-dd3123342f19    NULL    Resident 6      2019-11-16  52.9
be79adef-01c2-4fe9-86b1-9d42fe9fe012    NULL    Resident 7      2019-11-28  45.8
```

I would like then the following output, for the sake of an example, Resident 5:

```
Resident Name   Date        Value   %age Change
Resident 5      2019-11-01  62.05   n/a              
                2019-11-21  61      -1.69 
                2019-11-28  60.9    -1.85
```

Ultimately, I'm wanting to be able to say from the first date, or from a date entered via a variable to either the last date or another defined end date variable, what the percentage change has been for each resident in the list. Most residents will have numerous entries, I've just tried to give an example of one.

If this was in something like Delphi (old school, I know) then this would be relatively easy. However, for clarity reasons I'm trying to do as much of the processing in SQL Server. Can anyone offer any guidance? I'm aware of using LAG to perhaps find the previous row to use as a compare, but I'm finding it hard to get my head around going through the entire table for EACH resident at a time, and then generating the sort of list above. Or, is it better to just go through the entire table, and running a tally for each person (which would seem to be a much more complicated route).

Thanks
Ant

EDIT (20/12)

Thanks to @Zhorov, I am now very close. However, whereas before I did seem to be getting accurate results up to 10 entries before a div/0 came along, I am now getting wild scores and I'm sure it's because I've messed up along the way of implementing your suggestions. The code now is

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT ServiceUserID, ra.PersonID, ServiceUser, cn.DateDone, TRY_CAST((LEFT(SUBSTRING(cn.Fragment, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', cn.Fragment), 8000),
           PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(cn.Fragment, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', cn.Fragment), 8000) + 'X') -1)) AS REAL) AS [Weight], ra.ScoreMeaning
FROM [JSONCareNotes-HOME] cn 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [JSONRAs-HOME] ra ON ra.PersonID = cn.ServiceUserID
WHERE cn.SliderData LIKE '%weigh%'
AND cn.Fragment NOT LIKE '%weighed%'
)     
SELECT 
    ServiceUser,
    DateDone,
    [Weight],
    CASE 
       WHEN FIRST_VALUE([Weight] ) OVER (PARTITION BY [ServiceUser] ORDER BY DateDone ASC) = 0 THEN 0
       ELSE CONVERT(
               numeric(10, 2),
               [Weight] - FIRST_VALUE([Weight]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ServiceUser] ORDER BY DateDone ASC) / 
               FIRST_VALUE([Weight]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ServiceUser] ORDER BY DateDone ASC) * 
               100.0
            ) 
    END
    AS [Percentage]
FROM cte 
WHERE NOT([Weight] IS NULL) OR [Weight] = ' '
ORDER BY ServiceUser, DateDone ASC
```

This gives me the following results:

```
Resident 1  2019-11-16  83.1    -16.90
Resident 2  2019-11-16  63.8    -36.20
Resident 3  2019-11-10  54      -46.00
Resident 4  2019-11-16  81.5    -18.50
Resident 5  2019-11-01  62.05   -37.95
Resident 5  2019-11-21  61      -39.00
Resident 5  2019-11-28  60.9    -39.10
Resident 6  2019-11-16  52.9    -47.10
Resident 7  2019-11-14  40      -60.00
Resident 7  2019-11-21  42      -58.00
Resident 7  2019-11-28  45.8    -54.20
Resident 8  2019-11-21  48.1    -51.90
Resident 8  2019-11-28  50.2    -49.80
```

I'm missing something somewhere! Can anyone spot it for me? I think it's not resetting for each new resident?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a complicated example, but if I understand you correctly, the next approach, using `FIRST_VALUE()` and percentage calculations may help here:

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
    ServiceUser nvarchar(50), 
    DateDone date, 
    [Weight] numeric(10, 2)
)
INSERT INTO Data 
    (ServiceUser, DateDone, [Weight])
VALUES
    (N'Resident 1', '20191116', 83.1),
    (N'Resident 2', '20191116', 63.8),
    (N'Resident 3', '20191110', 54),
    (N'Resident 4', '20191116', 81.5),
    (N'Resident 5', '20191128', 60.9),
    (N'Resident 5', '20191121', 61),
    (N'Resident 5', '20191101', 62.05),
    (N'Resident 6', '20191116', 52.9),
    (N'Resident 7', '20191128', 45.8)
```

Statement:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM Data
    -- OR your complex statement 
)
SELECT 
    ServiceUser,
    DateDone,
    [Weight],
    CASE 
       WHEN FIRST_VALUE([Weight]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ServiceUser] ORDER BY DateDone ASC) = 0 THEN 0
       ELSE CONVERT(
               numeric(10, 2),
               ([Weight] - FIRST_VALUE([Weight]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ServiceUser] ORDER BY DateDone ASC)) / 
               FIRST_VALUE([Weight]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ServiceUser] ORDER BY DateDone ASC) * 
               100.0
            ) 
    END AS [Percentage]
FROM cte
```

Results:

```
------------------------------------------
ServiceUser DateDone    Weight  Percentage
------------------------------------------
Resident 1  2019-11-16  83.10    0.00
Resident 2  2019-11-16  63.80    0.00
Resident 3  2019-11-10  54.00    0.00
Resident 4  2019-11-16  81.50    0.00
Resident 5  2019-11-01  62.05    0.00
Resident 5  2019-11-21  61.00   -1.69
Resident 5  2019-11-28  60.90   -1.85
Resident 6  2019-11-16  52.90    0.00
Resident 7  2019-11-28  45.80    0.00
```

Update:

It seems, that your `[Weight]` column holds numbers as text. Try to convert these values with `TRY_CONVERT()` (`numeric(10, 2)` is just a test data type, use an appropriate numeric data type). One possible approach is:

```
SELECT ServiceUserID, PersonID, ServiceUser, DateDone, [Weight]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ServiceUserID, 
        PersonID, 
        ServiceUser, 
        DateDone, 
        TRY_CONVERT(
            numeric(10, 2),
            LEFT(SUBSTRING(cn.Fragment, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', cn.Fragment), 8000), PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(cn.Fragment, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', cn.Fragment), 8000) + 'X') -1)
        ) AS [Weight], 
        ra.ScoreMeaning
    FROM [JSONCareNotes-HOME] cn 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [JSONRAs-HOME] ra ON ra.PersonID = cn.ServiceUserID
    WHERE cn.SliderData LIKE '%weigh%' and cn.Fragment NOT LIKE '%weighed%'
    ) AS SubQueryAlias
WHERE [Weight] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ServiceUser, DateDone DESC
```

Comment: I've implemented this @zhorov, but it stops at 10 or so entries with a divided by 0 error. I've tried my best to put some `NullIf` commands, but I'm not sure exactly where they should do. Presumably, wrapped around [Weight], but could use some guidance.

Comment: @Ant Yes, it's possible, if you have `0` as first value in the `[Weigth]` column (not mentioned in the question). The answer is updated.

Comment: `SELECT 
    ServiceUser,
    DateDone,
    [Weight],
    CASE 
       WHEN FIRST_VALUE(cast([Weight] as real)) OVER (PARTITION BY [ServiceUser] ORDER BY DateDone ASC) = 0 THEN 0
       ELSE CONVERT(
               numeric(10, 2),
               (cast([Weight]as real) - FIRST_VALUE([Weight]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ServiceUser] ORDER BY DateDone ASC)) / 
               FIRST_VALUE(cast([Weight]as real)) OVER (PARTITION BY [ServiceUser] ORDER BY DateDone ASC) * 
               100.0
            ) 
    END AS [Percentage]
FROM cte 
where not([Weight] is null) or [Weight] = ' '`

Comment: I now have the above, but is saying Error converting datatype nvarchar to real. At first it was saying nvarchar to nvarchar, and following my own way I deduced I had to convert the [Weight]s. Once I did that, I was getting results (up to 10 rows, before div/0), but now I'm getting nothing but the nvarchar -> real. It does seem to reference the first line of the whole query when I double click the error, which is the one with all the PATINDEX commands. I'm so sorry, you've been so helpful. So close now!!

Comment: @Ant The column `[Weight]` seems to be a `varchar` ( ... `SUBSTRING(cn.Fragment, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', cn.Fragment), 8000) + 'X') -1) AS [Weight] ...`). If you want to make calculations with this column, you need to convert the values using `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST` functions. See updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Zhorov, thank you for all your help. I'm still, annoyingly and embarrassingly, stuck as the output has now changed. The fact that SQL doesn't follow the same kind of pointers of loops that I'm used to isn't helping here. If this were in Delphi I think I'd be all over it without much help, but I'm trying to keep it all in SQL Server if possible. Thanks for any further help you can give me! Sorry if I didn't give all the required info before.

Comment: Actually, I think I've sussed that it was because I didn't put brackets round the operation Weight - First Weight / First Weight. 

Making it (Weight - First Weight) / First Weight does the trick. Thank you @Zhorov for everything on this one!